# Should I strip comments from SQL/PLSQL file contents before running Statement.executeUpdate method

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

I have a program which take a set of sql/plsql file, mostly containing DDLs, and execute its contents after opening a Connection to database.

```
try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl, username, passwd)) {
    if (connection != null) {
        for (String sqlFile : sqlFiles) {
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            List<String> sqls = readFile(sqlFile);
            for (String sql : sqls) {
                statement.executeUpdate(sql);
            }
        }
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
}

// readFile(String fileName) returns the list of queries separated by "/" for .plsql and ";" for .sql files
```

I have seen many questions in stackoverflow regarding how to remove single line and multiline comments. But when I tested with files containing comments (both multiline and singleline), I didn't face any issues and the scripts are getting executed properly.

So, can I keep comments in sql string before executing Statememt.executeUpdate() method? Even if it works fine now with test data, will I face issues later?

Comment: If it works, why do you think it doesn't work? Also, are you talking about a comment + query or a comment within a query, or a comment in isolation? The first I expect to work in general (for most if not all database systems), I'm not so sure about the last one.

Comment: No need to remove comments, Oracle can deal with that without problems

Answer (score 0):

You won't have to remove comments from a script, just make sure you have correctly commented everything you should have to avoid failures.

Here's some good Oracle documentation on comments if you need more info:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/sql_elements006.htm#BEGIN